# Is Compress[] compatible between different Mathematica versions?

Tags: export, import, interoperability

[`Compress[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compress.html) was introduced in version 6 of Mathematica.  It gives a compressed version of expressions represented as a string of ASCII characters.  It preserves more information than the `InputForm` of expressions (for example it keeps packed arrays packed).

Are the strings returned by `Compress` compatible between versions?  Can a compressed expression created using version 6 be uncompressed in version 8?  What about the reverse (reading a version-8-compressed expression in 6 or 7)?

What happens if a version 8 specific object such as `Graph` is uncompressed in version 6 or 7?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Compress[expr]` will take an expression, convert it to a string, using some form, which would allows to recover the expression later on (most likely `InputForm` is used) and compress the string.

If the resulting compressed expression is uncompressed in an earlier version of *Mathematica*, the result is going to be an expression, which has no code associated with it, so it will, most likely, just remain unevaluated, if executed.

To reiterate, yes, `Compress`/`Uncompress` is cross version compatible, yet the result obtained on uncompressing, may not evaluate in earlier versions of *Mathematica*

Comment: I doubt that it uses `InputForm` or any usual string representation of expressions, for two reasons: 1. Converting to InputForm is slower: try `data = RandomReal[1, 1000000];` `ToString[data, InputForm]; // Timing` `Compress[data]; // Timing` 2. It preserves packed arrays: `Developer`PackedArrayQ[Uncompress[Compress[{1, 2, 3}]]]` vs `Developer`PackedArrayQ[
 Uncompress[Compress[Developer`ToPackedArray[{1, 2, 3}]]]]`.  Or perhaps it is only a few objects that it treats specially?

Comment: @Szabolcs I am sure it is not `InputForm` literally, but rather some form of serialization used. Something similar to what happens with MathLink. I suspect it does not unpack either.

Comment: Would you go as far to say it's relatively safe to archive data in this format (i.e. 9 and 10 are not *likely* to break compatibility)?  The only good alternative I know, WDX, is very very slow to read and write. (Of course for long term archiving of important things I'd just use a text table, but large and structured data is very convenient to hold in the form of Mathematica expressions)

Comment: As for graphs, since these are dynamic objects, they will presumably trigger the dynamic content warning and return some warning/error when being allowed to evaluate.

Comment: I'd guess that `Compress`/`Uncompress` will be based on the internal representation of expressions, which I think is most closely revealed by `FullForm`. As for Graph: `Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}] // Compress` will be uncompressed to `Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, Null}]` in version 7, that's `Global\`Graph` to be precise.

Answer (score 1):

I can only talk about forward compatibility right now. So far I have encountered no problems with compressed/uncompressed expression from versions 6, 7 and 8.

It would be quite against the usually very thorough compatibility policy of WRI to change the behaviour of a documented function that is obviously intended to store data in a persistent fashion. But then one of the WRI people would have to comment about that (I am just assuming).